# Testing for multiple sequences of characters in a string in Python

Tags: python, string-matching

I have an incoming string made up of 1s and 0s; built bit by bit.  The tail end of this will at some point match one of two patterns, say, 1001 and 0101 and when it does, it terminates the search (this is one iteration - and the patterns will vary per iteration).

I want to test for **either** pattern, and then keep an account of which one terminated the string and so this iteration. I then need to repeat the process - with different patterns - on the incoming string.

I have coded this up, but it's ugly imho, and I'm sure there's a much more elegant and efficient way to do this in Python (at which I'm a newbie really).  The way I do it at the moment is like this:

```
pattern1 = getPattern1()
pattern2 = getPattern2()


while 1:

    s += nextBit()

    if s.count(pattern1) and s.count(pattern2): 

        if s.find(pattern1) < s.find(pattern2):
            tot1 += 1
        else:
            tot2 += 1

        s = ''

     ...
```

Comment: If I'd have used Or, the next line [s.find() ...] would have been a problem.

I've since discovered endswith() however, and so I now have:

    while not s.endswith((pattern1, pattern2)):

Comment: So, I now have  
  
`while not s.endswith((pattern1, pattern2)):`  
`s += nextBit()`  
``  
`if s.endswith(pattern1):`  
`...`  
  
The thing I don't like about this is that it duplicates a test that's already been carried out.

Comment: don't comment on your own question. [edit] the question instead.

Answer (score 0):

First, write readable code that is correct and expresses your intent clearly then measure performance and optimize if necessary.

You could use a regex to search and extract the patterns simultaneously:

```
import re

# match any of the patterns literally at the end of string
regex = re.compile(r"(?:%s)$" % "|".join(map(re.escape, patterns)))
def getpattern(s):
    m = regex.search(s)
    return m and m.group()

maxlen = max(map(len, patterns))
count = dict.fromkeys(patterns, 0)
s = ""
for bit in iter(nextBit, ""): # get bits until empty string
    s += bit
    p = getpattern(s)
    if p: # found pattern
       count[p] += 1
       s = ""
    elif len(s) > maxlen: # limit s size
       s = s[-maxlen:]
print(count)
```

If the patterns are rare in the input then `.endswith(patterns)`-based solution might be more efficient.

To speed thing up, consider reading more than one bit at a time and counting patterns in a larger buffer.

Comment: And how do you use a regexp when the patterns vary with every iteration?

Comment: you generate a new regex whenever necessary.